# Generate Bibliography file from multiple files with Pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc, bibtex

I have several chapters with citations. My citation file is in bibtex format. I would like to create a formatted bibliography that includes all the citations from the chapters in a single file (publisher prefers DOCX). How can I do this?

Comment: I'm unclear: do you want to create a file with **just** the bibliography, or do you want to build a normal document which combines all chapters?

Comment: A file with just the bibliography -- a file that combines the citations from multiple chapters/files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the bibtex file contains no additional citations, then it would be sufficient to have a small `nocite.md` Markdown file to generate the bibliography:

```
---
nocite: '@*'
---

# Bibliography
```

Calling `pandoc --output=bibliography.docx --bibliography YOUR_BIBTEX.bib nocite.md` will generate a docx file with formatted entries for all items in `YOUR_BIBTEX.bib`.

---

The more general case is that the bibtex file contains additional entries which should be omitted from the bibliography. One will need a way to limit output to citations used in the document(s). A good method is to use a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to rewrite the document as needed.

```lua
-- save this file as "bib-only.lua"

local cites = {}

-- collect all citations
function Cite (cite)
  table.insert(cites, cite)
end

-- use citations, but omit rest of the document
function Pandoc (doc)
  doc.meta.nocite = cites
  doc.blocks = {}
  return doc
end
```

Running

```
pandoc --lua-filter bib-only.lua -o bib.docx chapter1.md chapter2.md chapter3.md
```

should give the desired output.